# perf version not matching with my kernel version

Tags: linux, debian

I'm currently working on Raspberry pi zero.
When i write:

```
perf --version
```

> /usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_4.14: not found E: linux-perf-4.14
>   is not installed.

when i do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-perf
```

Then:

> linux-perf is already the newest version (4.9+80+deb9u4+rpi1)
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 216 not upgraded.

```
sudo apt-get install perf_4.14
```

> E: Unable to locate package perf_4.14
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob
>
> 'perf_4.14' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'perf_4.14'

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-base
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-common

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-$(uname -r)
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.14.79
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.14.79'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.14.79'

Please help me in this!

Thanks

Comment: may be try updating to the latest kernel sudo rpi-update

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to support programming code problems. I'd recommend deleting here and searching at, and reposting to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @Saiprasant its not advisable to do rpi-update; its mentioned in a lot of blogs. Thats why I skipped this part.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same problem in the k8s pod environment.

Install perf in Debian GNU/Linux 10:

`sudo apt install linux-perf`

Tried to use perf, but reported an error:

```
:~/perf-tools$ sudo perf -h
/usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_5.4: not found
E: linux-perf-5.4 is not installed.
```

After research, I found that /usr/bin/perf used `uname -r` to get the linux kernel version of the host instead of the version of the container.

So I solved it by renaming it.

`sudo cp /usr/bin/perf_4.19 /usr/bin/perf_5.4`

Comment: u save my life.

Comment: I had the same problem with WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

on Debian 11  Bullseye
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"

```
1. apt install linux-perf
2. sudo cp /usr/bin/perf_5.10 /usr/bin/perf_5.15
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `Debian 11`:

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

My linux kernel version is:

```
# uname -r
6.3.3
```

###### perf_5.10 is already installed:

```
# dpkg -l linux-perf
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-===================================================
ii  linux-perf     5.10.191-1   amd64        Performance analysis tools for Linux (meta-package)
```

But while running the perf command, I was getting the following error:

```
# perf top --sort cpu,comm,dso
/usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_6.3: not found
E: linux-perf-6.3 is not installed.
```

So, I copied the existing file to the `/usr/bin/perf_6.3`:

```
# cp /usr/bin/perf_5.10 /usr/bin/perf_6.3
```

Now perf command started working as expected.