# Using perf inside podman container

Tags: perf, podman

I want to profile an application compiled with debug symbols:

```
$ file ../../bin/linux-x86_64/simulator
../../bin/linux-x86_64/simulator: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=156bbd57d203d72f4226ed4ad0727bcf472f83ef, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

It runs inside a podman container. The container is a debian 11 and the host is an ubuntu 22.04. I have been able to use perf with it before but i must be forgetting some necessary configuration.

Outside the container i did:

> sudo sysctl kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1

Then to enter the container:

> podman run --privileged --entrypoint=bash --network=host --rm -it -v ./st.cmd/:/opt/ad-sim-epics-ioc/iocBoot/iocsimulator/st.cmd -v /home/marco:/home/marco ghcr.io/cnpem/ad-sim-epics-ioc:v1.0.0

And finally to install perf:

> apt-get update && apt-get install linux-perf

To get the profiler results:

```
perf record -g ./st.cmd # st.cmd is an interpreter with shebang poiting to ../../bin/linux-x86_64/simulator
```

At the first try, system will complain:

> /usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_5.15: not found

But since i found [several people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259373/perf-version-not-matching-with-my-kernel-version) claiming that its okay to copy or symbolically link perf:

> ln -s /usr/bin/perf_5.10 /usr/bin/perf_5.15

Finally:

```
perf record -g ./st.cmd
(do things...)
^C
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.128 MB perf.data (2500 samples) ]

perf script -F +pid > script.txt
```

But absolutely no userspace function is shown, only kernel kallsyms:

[image]

I tried running the container with and without --privileged flag, tried perf record --call-graph dwarf, perf record --call-graph fp, and nothing. I vividly remember being able to see the functions just with perf record -g... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for anyone who helps this lost, desperate soul.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it was all actually the kernel's fault, i think.

Sometime ago, before I even thought about profiling, I received the following message from the server:

[image]

But as it was a production server and the kernel update caused a mess with some drivers, I fixed the kernel version to 5.15.0-91 in my /etc/default/grub file.

Turns out the perf installation I had was from before couldn't deal with the older kernel version. When i remembered this and updated the kernel (thus temporarily sacrificing my operation) perf started working even inside the container.